# Need Some help to refactor or optimize the code in javascript object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, conditional-operator

I have tried writing the array of objects using ternary but still I am thinking to refactor the common properties between them if someone could help me with this would be helpful.

```
   const{address } = A

  data: conditionalValue ? [
        { text: text },
        { building: address },
        { ' ': pincode }
      ]:
      [
        { text: text },
        { building: address },
        { ' ': pincode },
        { 'somevalue': someValue1 },
        { ' ': otherValue},
      ],
```

still the  { text: text },{ building: address },{ ' ': pincode } objects are same between 2 condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some destructuring on a array of additional values:

```js
const conditionalValue = false;
const data = [
  { text: 'text' },
  { building: 'address' },
  { ' ': 'pincode' },
  ...(
    conditionalValue
      ? [{ 'somevalue': 'someValue1' },{ ' ': 'otherValue'}]
      : []
  )
];

console.log(data);
```

However, I think it might be cleaner to just push your other values into the `data` array.